# Validate Json(Entity) occasionally and not compulsorily

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a requirement where I can allow an entity to be saved in DB without any validations but during final posting, I need to validate the entity else not allow the entity to be posted until it is validated. How do I accomplish this using validation annotations in Spring boot? I used the @Notnull etc annotations but it is not allowing to save in DB until the entity is validated. In short, how to skip annotated validations as per use case in Spring boot?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`?

Comment: u can use required=false property

Comment: read about @Retantion annotation it might be help you